# Affecting another object's fields with methods

Tags: c++, class, methods, objective-c++

I have to write a program with classes that is a simulation of animals interfering with each other in a two-dimensional array. I am trying to do this with a one-dimensional array and I am stuck with the problem of one animal hitting the other one. I have no idea how to do such a thing. I declared an array as shown below:

```
animal **tab = new animal*[3];
tab[0] = new wolf(30, 0);
tab[1] = new sheep(100, 0);
tab[2] = new wolf(30, 0);
int n=1;
if (tab[3 + n] = tab[4])
{
    cout << "HP left " <<  << endl;
}
```

Here is the code for the wolf class:

```
class wolf : public animal {
    public:
    int atack()
    {
        return DMG;
    }

    int life()
    {
        return HP;
    }

    wolf(int a, int b):animal(a, b)
    {
        DMG = b;
        HP = a;
    }
};
```

How do I have a wolf damage a sheep's life. Do I have to make a global function or do something else?

Answer (score 1):

Objects interact through their methods. It looks like you have a class Animal from which your Wolf class inherits and hopefully your Sheep class inherits from Animal as well.  Since you don't declare a HP or damage variable in Wolf I'm guessing it's already in your Animal class.

In your Animal class, you should create a method called receiveDamage or something similar. That method modifies the HP.

```
void receiveDamage(int damage) {
    HP -= damage;
    if (HP <= 0) {
        cout << "Animal died" << endl;
    }
}
```

Now in your wolf class that can attack, you want your attack method to take a target animal.

```
void attack(Animal animal) {
    animal.receiveDamage(DMG)
}
```

Now when a wolf attacks another animal (a sheep or another wolf or anything else that inherits from Animal) the damage will be applied to the HP.